# Как удалить несколько слов (подстрок) из строки

Tags: java, строки

Есть задача, нужно удалить несколько подстрок которые поступают в массиве из заданной строки. Не могу понять как это реализовать. Пока пришел к такому коду, но он работает не верно.

```
        String phrase = "this is sparta";
        String[] words = new String[]{"is", "this"};
        String resultStr = "";
        String[] strArr = phrase.split(" ");

        for (String str : strArr) {
            for (String word : words) {
                if (!str.equals(word)) {
                    resultStr = resultStr + str + " ";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: потому что этот код не удаляет из строки подстроки. Он "удаляет" элементы из списка.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь Стрингбилдером и стройте новую строку. Проходите по исходной строке циклом, если слово нужно, то лепите к стрингбилдеру, если нет -то переходите к следующему слову

Comment: @had0ukenб ну тогда стримом, а не  циклом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение с использованием `String::replaceAll` -- для этого массив подстрок следует объединить при помощи операции `|`.  Если нужно будет убрать оставшиеся пробелы, к результату можно применить `String::trim`:

```java
public static String cleanPhrase(String phrase, String ... words) {
    return phrase.replaceAll(String.join("|", words), "").trim();
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println("'" + cleanPhrase("this is sparta", "is", "this") + "'");
// -> 'sparta'
```

---

Если подстроки могут содержать не только буквы/цифры, но и некоторые символы, которые используются в регулярных выражениях и нуждаются в экранировании, то придется преобразовать каждую подстроку в литерал при помощи `Pattern::quote`:

```java
public static String cleanString(String str, String ... subs) {
    String replace = Arrays.stream(subs)
            .map(Pattern::quote)
            .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
    return str.replaceAll(replace, "").trim();
}

System.out.println("'" + cleanString("|this is (sparta)|", "is", "this", "|", "(", ")") + "'");
// -> 'sparta'
```